From command line build to CMakeLists.txt
I'm having issues translating my command line executable creation to a the correct CMake command in my CMakeLists.txt. Running the following in command line:
g++ PRIMPP.cpp -O3 -march=native -fopenmp
works well but i can't seem to get CMake to actually use the -march=native and -fopenmp options.
So far I have tried all of
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS} -march=native -fopenmp")
set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /openmp /march:native")
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /openmp /march:native")
set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /openmp /march:native")

to no avail.
Below is the full CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4...3.18)
SET(BUILD_MODE Release)

project(pybindtest)
add_subdirectory(pybind11)
add_subdirectory(eigen)

pybind11_add_module(PRIMPP PRIMPP/PRIMPP.cpp)

find_package(OpenMP)
link_libraries(march=native fopenmp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS} -march=native -fopenmp")
set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /openmp /march:native")
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /openmp /march:native")
set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /openmp /march:native")




I build with
cmake --build . --config Release
Using cmake --build . --config Release --verbose outputs
PS C:\Users\aen\Desktop\PartiellInternModell\build> cmake ..
-- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.40.33812.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.40.33812.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.40.33807/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.40.33807/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- pybind11 v2.14.0 dev1
-- Found PythonInterp: C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/python3.12.exe (found suitable version "3.12.4", minimum required is "3.8")
-- Found PythonLibs: c:/python312/libs/python312.lib
-- Performing Test HAS_MSVC_GL_LTCG
-- Performing Test HAS_MSVC_GL_LTCG - Success
-- 
-- Configured Eigen 3.4.90
--
-- Found OpenMP_C: -openmp (found version "2.0")
-- Found OpenMP_CXX: -openmp (found version "2.0")
-- Found OpenMP: TRUE (found version "2.0")
-- Configuring done (11.0s)
-- Generating done (0.1s)
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/aen/Desktop/PartiellInternModell/build
PS C:\Users\aen\Desktop\PartiellInternModell\build> cmake --build . --config Release --verbose  
Change Dir: 'C:/Users/aen/Desktop/PartiellInternModell/build'

Run Build Command(s): "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/MSBuild/Current/Bin/amd64/MSBuild.exe" ALL_BUILD.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=17.0 /v:n
MSBuild version 17.10.4+10fbfbf2e for .NET Framework
Build started 2024-08-30 10:31:59.

Project "C:\Users\aen\Desktop\PartiellInternModell\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
Project "C:\Users\aen\Desktop\PartiellInternModell\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (1) is building "C:\Users\aen\Desktop\PartiellInternModell\build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\".
  Structured output is enabled. The formatting of compiler diagnostics will reflect the error hierarchy. See https://aka.ms/cpp/structured-output for more details.
  Creating directory "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
  Touching "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
CustomBuild:
  1>Checking Build System
FinalizeBuildStatus:
  Deleting file "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
  Touching "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\ZERO_CHECK.lastbuildstate".
Done Building Project "C:\Users\aen\Desktop\PartiellInternModell\build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (default targets).

Project "C:\Users\aen\Desktop\PartiellInternModell\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (1) is building "C:\Users\aen\Desktop\PartiellInternModell\build\PRIMPP.vcxproj" (3) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "PRIMPP.dir\Release\".
  Structured output is enabled. The formatting of compiler diagnostics will reflect the error hierarchy. See https://aka.ms/cpp/structured-output for more details.
  Creating directory "C:\Users\aen\Desktop\PartiellInternModell\build\Release\".
  Creating directory "PRIMPP.dir\Release\PRIMPP.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "PRIMPP.dir\Release\PRIMPP.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
  Touching "PRIMPP.dir\Release\PRIMPP.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
CustomBuild:
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/aen/Desktop/PartiellInternModell/CMakeLists.txt
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe /c /nologo /W1 /WX- /diagnostics:column /MP /O2 /Ob2 /GL /D _WINDLL /D _MBCS /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D NDEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Release\"" /D PRIMPP_EXPORTS /EHsc /MD /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /GR /openmp /Fo"PRIMPP.dir\Release\\" /Fd"PRIMPP.dir\Release\vc143.pdb" /external:W0 /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue  /external:I "C:/Users/aen/Desktop/PartiellInternModell/pybind11/include" /external:I "
  c:/python312/Include" -march=native -fopenmp /march:native -march=native -fopenmp /march:native /bigobj C:\Users\aen\Desktop\PartiellInternModell\PRIMPP\PRIMPP.cpp
cl : command line  warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '-march=native' [C:\Users\aen\Desktop\PartiellInternModell\build\PRIMPP.vcxproj]
cl : command line  warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '-fopenmp' [C:\Users\aen\Desktop\PartiellInternModell\build\PRIMPP.vcxproj]
cl : command line  warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '/march:native' [C:\Users\aen\Desktop\PartiellInternModell\build\PRIMPP.vcxproj]
cl : command line  warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '-march=native' [C:\Users\aen\Desktop\PartiellInternModell\build\PRIMPP.vcxproj]
cl : command line  warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '-fopenmp' [C:\Users\aen\Desktop\PartiellInternModell\build\PRIMPP.vcxproj]
cl : command line  warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '/march:native' [C:\Users\aen\Desktop\PartiellInternModell\build\PRIMPP.vcxproj]
  PRIMPP.cpp
Link:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"C:\Users\aen\Desktop\PartiellInternModell\build\Release\PRIMPP.cp312-win_amd64.pyd" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO c:\python312\libs\python312.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /PDB:"C:/Users/aen/Desktop/PartiellInternModell/build/Rel
  ease/PRIMPP.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /LTCG /LTCGOUT:"PRIMPP.dir\Release\PRIMPP.cp312-win_amd64.iobj" /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"C:/Users/aen/Desktop/PartiellInternModell/build/Release/PRIMPP.lib" /MACHINE:X64  /machine:x64 /DLL PRIMPP.dir\Release\PRIMPP.obj
     Creating library C:/Users/aen/Desktop/PartiellInternModell/build/Release/PRIMPP.lib and object C:/Users/aen/Desktop/PartiellInternModell/build/Release/PRIMPP.exp
  Generating code
  Finished generating code
  PRIMPP.vcxproj -> C:\Users\aen\Desktop\PartiellInternModell\build\Release\PRIMPP.cp312-win_amd64.pyd
FinalizeBuildStatus:
  Deleting file "PRIMPP.dir\Release\PRIMPP.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
  Touching "PRIMPP.dir\Release\PRIMPP.tlog\PRIMPP.lastbuildstate".
Done Building Project "C:\Users\aen\Desktop\PartiellInternModell\build\PRIMPP.vcxproj" (default targets).

PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "x64\Release\ALL_BUILD\".
  Structured output is enabled. The formatting of compiler diagnostics will reflect the error hierarchy. See https://aka.ms/cpp/structured-output for more details.
  Creating directory "x64\Release\ALL_BUILD\ALL_BUILD.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "x64\Release\ALL_BUILD\ALL_BUILD.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
  Touching "x64\Release\ALL_BUILD\ALL_BUILD.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
CustomBuild:
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/aen/Desktop/PartiellInternModell/CMakeLists.txt
FinalizeBuildStatus:
  Deleting file "x64\Release\ALL_BUILD\ALL_BUILD.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
  Touching "x64\Release\ALL_BUILD\ALL_BUILD.tlog\ALL_BUILD.lastbuildstate".
Done Building Project "C:\Users\aen\Desktop\PartiellInternModell\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default targets).


Build succeeded.

"C:\Users\aen\Desktop\PartiellInternModell\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\aen\Desktop\PartiellInternModell\build\PRIMPP.vcxproj" (default target) (3) ->
(ClCompile target) ->
  cl : command line  warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '-march=native' [C:\Users\aen\Desktop\PartiellInternModell\build\PRIMPP.vcxproj]
  cl : command line  warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '-fopenmp' [C:\Users\aen\Desktop\PartiellInternModell\build\PRIMPP.vcxproj]
  cl : command line  warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '/march:native' [C:\Users\aen\Desktop\PartiellInternModell\build\PRIMPP.vcxproj]
  cl : command line  warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '-march=native' [C:\Users\aen\Desktop\PartiellInternModell\build\PRIMPP.vcxproj]
  cl : command line  warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '-fopenmp' [C:\Users\aen\Desktop\PartiellInternModell\build\PRIMPP.vcxproj]
  cl : command line  warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '/march:native' [C:\Users\aen\Desktop\PartiellInternModell\build\PRIMPP.vcxproj]

    6 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:18.09


I don't see in your CMakeLists.txt compiling of main.cpp, like you do in the command line. Or do you want to apply flags to some other targets? Which ones?

@Tsyvarev Sorry, I edited the line, PRIMPP.cpp is the file with main().

So, which flags you actually observe when use your CMakeLists.txt? If you use make for build the project, then you could add VERBOSE=1 parameter to it for see the exact command lines.

Edited the post!

@Tsyvarev Should be correct now

What this link_libraries(march=native fopenmp) suppose to do? Did you read documentation of link_libraries?

@MarekR One of several hail Marys from me, based on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49273341/convert-compiler-command-line-to-cmakelists-txt-for-casablanca-rest-sdk

You are compiling C++ files so you should remove anything with C_FLAGS in the name. OpenMP exposes OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS and OpenMP_CXX_INCLUDE_DIRS that you should use.

Secondly, you need to figure out for yourself if you want to use the MSVC compiler or g++. Explicitly adding flags that the compiler does not understand is only muddying things.

Why not just start form an example?

You are using wrong approach when searching for a solution for your problem. Do not search for "how to convert". Instead, you need firstly to understand what your options means. Then search for achieving that meaning with CMake. E.g. "cmake use openmp" would find that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23163075/how-to-compile-an-mpi-included-c-program-using-cmake

Firs to all you should start form example provided pybind11.
Please do not use old cmake pattersn, use modern patters. One of the good practices is not to touch CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS or use link_libraries.
I would fix your CmakeLists.txt this way:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4...3.18)
project(pybindtest)

# add_subdirectory(pybind11)
# add_subdirectory(eigen)

# ---------------

find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)
add_library(build_settings INTERFACE)

target_compile_options(build_settings
    INTERFACE
        $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}>
        $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:C>:${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}>)

target_link_libraries(build_settings INTERFACE ${OpenMP_CXX_LIBRARIES})

if (MSVC)
    target_compile_options(build_settings INTERFACE /W4)
else()
    set(PRIM_ARCH native CACHE STRING "Target architecture")
    target_compile_options(build_settings INTERFACE -march=${PRIM_ARCH})
    target_compile_options(build_settings INTERFACE -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# ---------------

set(PYBIND11_FINDPYTHON ON)
find_package(pybind11 CONFIG REQUIRED)

# ---------------
pybind11_add_module(PRIMPP PRIMPP/PRIMPP.cpp)
target_link_libraries(PRIMPP PUBLIC build_settings)

Didn't test it, so it may missing something similar to: target_link_libraries(build_settings INTERFACE ...
Note that if (MSVC) will alter which flags will be used depending for which compiler you will configure the project. From logs I can see that you are using MSVC and you feed there gcc flags.
Here are some related documentation links:

OpenMP cmake package
target_compile_options

